# How to call services in IOS using Parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

i have given a url and three parameters to use and call those services in application, i have to create a login page with a id, user name and password, if they match then the user should move to next page, am bit confused to how to start the code. can anyone help me in this. please let me know the code with any example which you have.

Comment: do you know how to call url ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I am having the code in which login and password and apikey matches and if all are correct then navigate to other page...

```
-(void)login
{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Login URL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

  [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=admin&password=testing&api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6"];

       NSData *postData = [mapData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(error == nil)
        {

            NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if(error!=nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self checkUserSuccessfulLogin:json];
            });
        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);

        }


    }];


    [postDataTask resume];

}
- (void)checkUserSuccessfulLogin:(id)json
{
  //  NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;


    if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login"])
    {
        if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"login"] boolValue])
        {

            if(checkBoxSelected == YES)
            {
                NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                NSString* textField1Text = usernameField.text;
                [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

                NSString *textField2Text = passwordField.text;
                [defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];
                [defaults synchronize];
            }
            NSString *strID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField1Text"];
            NSString *strPWD = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField2Text"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];
          NSString *strUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            [self saveLoginFileToDocDir:dictionary];


            ItemManagement *i = [[ItemManagement alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Unsuccessful, Try again.");
            UIAlertView *alertLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Wrong Username Or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertLogin show];
        }
    }
}




- (void)saveLoginFileToDocDir:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

    BOOL flag = [dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:true];

    if (flag)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Saved");
    }

}
```

May be it will help you definitely .